# Avoid multiple WMI calls to same computer?

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am querying WMI classes on many remote computers using Powershell.

I have the following that works pretty well but since doing anything to a remote computer it takes some time and I'm looking to minimize that:

```
$file = Get-Content c:\temp\bitlocker\non-compliant-wksn1.txt
foreach ($ComputerName in $file) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Quiet) {
        $Hostname = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName).Name
        $model = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName).Model
        $OS = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName).Version
        $TpmActivate = (Get-WMIObject -Namespace "root/CIMV2/Security/MicrosoftTpm" -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_TPM" -ComputerName $ComputerName).IsActivated_InitialValue
        $TpmEnabled = (Get-WMIObject -Namespace "root/CIMV2/Security/MicrosoftTpm" -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_TPM" -ComputerName $ComputerName).IsEnabled_InitialValue
        $TpmOwned = (Get-WMIObject -Namespace "root/CIMV2/Security/MicrosoftTpm" -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_TPM" -ComputerName $ComputerName).IsOwned_InitialValue
        $Encrypted = (Get-WMIObject -Namespace "root/CIMV2/Security/MicrosoftVolumeEncryption" -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume WHERE DriveLetter='C:'" -ComputerName $ComputerName).ProtectionStatus
        write-host $ComputerName "`t" $Hostname "`t" $model "`t" $OS "`t" $TpmActivate "`t" $TpmEnabled "`t" $TpmOwned "`t" "C:" "`t" $Encrypted
        }
    else {
        write-host $Computername "`t" "Offline"
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, I am making 2 remote calls to get 2 values from Win32_ComputerSystem and 3 remote calls to get 3 values from Win32_TPM.  Is it possible to take these 5 remote calls and somehow reduce them to 2 remote calls (one for each class) that returns all of the information I need and storing them in my variables (hoping that will speed things up)?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of these calls, as you note, makes a remote call:

```
$Hostname = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName).Name
$model = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName).Model
$OS = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName).Version**strong text**
```

Instead get the complete WMI object in one call and then extract the required properties:

```
$c = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
$Hostname = $c.Name
$model = $c.Model
$OS = $c.Version
```

Even better, only get the required properties from that object:

```
$c = Get-WmiObject -Query 'select Name, Model, Version from Win32_ComputerSystem' -ComputerName $ComputerName
$Hostname = $c.Name
$model = $c.Model
$OS = $c.Version
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to do this.  Worked like a charm!  Thanks

Comment: Minor error in the last two snippets, `Version` is a property of `Win32_OperatingSystem`, not `Win32_ComputerSystem`.  Still, +1 for showing how to minimize the number of `Get-WmiObject` invocations, and even better for mentioning to only retrieve the properties you need.  An alternative would be to use the `-Property` parameter and have the cmdlet build the query for you: `$c = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName -Property Name, Model`.